Error: `headers` was called outside a request scope
I have just installed Authjs v5 on my nextjs14 project; the setup is as the documentation says and it's in bare-bones condition I haven't added any thing to the config files.
the proble is when I try to signIn, I get this error saying: Error: headers was called outside a request scope. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-dynamic-api-wrong-context.
how to solve this problem? I checked the documentation but couldn't find anything helpful.
//my handler in a clinet component
  function handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    signIn("credentials", { email, password });


// auth.js setup
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
     let user = {email: credentials.email}
console.log(user)
return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
});


and i have the route.js file in app/api/[...nextauth]/route.js
import { handlers } from "@/auth"; // Referring to the auth.ts we just created
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;


what seems to be the problem?
tried to test the signin functionality, I was expecting to see my user credentials in authorize function.

This is only happening when using npm. I tried running the same project in two different environments, one with npm and one with bun and the one with bun is working just fine.

Faced this problem, using next-authV5
I forgot to add 'use server' in my lib/action.ts file, where i actually call "signIn" method. See link

Thank you so much, it was the case for me

Use signIn() from "next-auth/react".
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";


This! You have the read the import section carefully :D
https://authjs.dev/getting-started/session-management/login

Based on jidi1f's response, I did a little trial and error and finally got to work after a few hours of frustration.
First, check out the link on his answer again for the concept of server actions, is easy to miss that it works excatly for what we need here (call a server function from a client component), as we cannot send functions as parameters to client components.
Now for the working code, move whatever call of the signIn function to the server component, here it is located under src/lib/auth-action.ts
'use server'
import { signIn } from './auth'

export async function SignIn() {
  return await signIn('google')
}

here's my auth file for reference, it is the same as the documentation, also located in the lib folder under lib/auth
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import google from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [google],
})

Finally, call it from the client component, this one is set with the 'use client' directive on top:
'use client'
import { SignIn } from '@/lib/auth-action'

export function ConnectForm() {
  return (
    <form
      id="ConnectBox"
      className="mt-6 flex flex-col"
      action={() => {
        SignIn()
      }}
    >
      {/* ...some other code */}

      <button type="submit" className="self-end w-full">
        Next page
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}

tested and working on Next 14.2.3 and Next Auth 5.0.0-beta.18

Tested and approved.

I suspect you have "use client" at the top of the file you are trying to carry out the authentication logic on the client, which you can't do with the Authjs serverside auth and that is what causes the error you are seeing.
I am using "Sendgrid" email provider but you should be able to implement similar for your scenario or convert yours to magic link as it's far easier IMO and safer.
I have got around it using some serverside logic and making a POST request to it.
Important note: I am having issues with the redirectTo from Authjs, so I am getting the session using;
const session = await auth();
And passing it as a prop to my AuthForm.ts (Client component) and using a useEffect to send the user to my /dashboard route.
<AuthForm session={session} />
Client side;
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Button from "../ui/Button";
import Input from "../ui/Input";

type AuthFormProps = {
    session: any;
};

export default function AuthForm({ session }: AuthFormProps) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");

    const handleEmailSignIn = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/api/login", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorData = await response.json();
                console.error("Failed to send login link:", errorData);
                return;
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data.message);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Fetch error:", error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (session) {
            window.location.href = "/dashboard";
        }
    }, [session]);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleEmailSignIn}>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-[300px]">
                <Input
                    label={"Email"}
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="dog@wifhat.com"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <Button cta="Send login link" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

Serverside;
/api/login/route.ts

import { signIn } from "@/app/auth";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    try {
        const data = await request.json();
        const email = data.email;
        await signIn("sendgrid", { email, redirect: false });
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({
                message: "Check your email for the login link!",
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                status: 200,
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during sign-in:", error);
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({
                error: "Failed to send email",
                message: error,
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                status: 500,
            }
        );
    }
}



When using "use client" @Vasilije Repović answer is the right. The seems very complicated. In Auth.js this can be achieved with configuration of the auth.ts file

This error happens because the "signIn()" is imported from "@/auth.js" and not from "next-auth/react". So it can only be called in the server environment.
Create a server action:-
"use server";

import { signIn } from "./auth";

export const signInWithCredentials = async (credentials: {
  identifier: string;
  password: string;
}) => {
  try {
    const res = await signIn("credentials", credentials);
    console.log(res);

    return {
      success: true,
      message: "Sign in successfully",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {
      success: false,
      message: (error as Error).message,
    };
  }
};

Then call the server action in your form on submit:-
async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof signinSchema>) {
    console.log(values);
    try {
      const updatedAction = signInWithCredentials.bind(null, values);

      await updatedAction();

      toast({
        title: "Sign in successful",
        description: `Welcome back ${values.identifier}`,
      });

      router.push("/");

      form.reset();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      toast({
        title: "Sign in failed",
        description:
          (error as Error).message ??
          "Unexpected error occured while signing in",
        variant: "destructive",
      });
    }
  }

Here, I am using the "Form" component from "shadcn ui". You can use it if your form is in the client component.
Alternatively, you can use "signIn()" from "next-auth/react" and add to the "onSubmit()" function.
I hope this will resolve your error and reduce your headache.

My errors are:
In route /profile a header property was accessed directly with `headers().get('x-forwarded-proto')`. `headers()` should be awaited before using its value. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis
In route /profile a header property was accessed directly with `headers().get('x-forwarded-host')`. `headers()` should be awaited before using its value. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis
In route /profile a header property was accessed directly with `headers().get('x-forwarded-proto')`. `headers()` should be awaited before using its value. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis
In route /profile a header property was accessed directly with `headers().get('cookie')`. `headers()` should be awaited before using its value. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis

I found that in the file /.next/server/middleware.js, in section
/***/ "(middleware)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.35.3/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/utils/env.js":

there is
const detectedHost = headers.get(\"x-forwarded-host\") ?? headers.get(\"host\");\n        const detectedProtocol = headers.get(\"x-forwarded-proto\") ?? protocol ?? \"https\";

So why Auth.js v5 use this here without await? node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@5.0.0-beta.22_next@15.0.0-rc.0_@opentelemetry+api@1.9.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-fb9a90f_xjyb3ulkl4v2uilrzrt3n7ec4e/node_modules/next-auth/src/lib/index.ts
auth() > initAuth() > const _headers = headers()

Adding 'use server' to middleware.ts no help.

There are separate calls for client/server. Use next-auth/react on client and @/auth for server.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
